# MySQL query order by multiple items not working

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I´m currently working on a query that must pull up titles ordered by

1. Exact match,
2. Followed by Highest amount of matched words first,
3. Followed by First word in query is first word in title,
4. Followed by Alphabetical order.

Something like this:

```
SELECT title

FROM title

WHERE title LIKE '%keyword%' OR LIKE '%keyword1%' OR LIKE '%keyword2%'

order by

case when title == 'keyword' then 0 else 1 end asc, 

((title like '%keyword1%') + (title like '%keyword2%')) desc, 

case when title like 'keyword1%' then 0 else 1 end asc, 

title asc;
```

I tested with 8 titles.

Search: "Buford Christmas".

Result:

- Buford Christmas
- Christmas Buford
- Mr Buford
- Mr Buford
- Buford and Lisa
- Lisa Christmas
- Me Christmas
- Me Buford Lisa.

I need to find a way to sort the titles so that "Buford and Lisa" should be before "Mr Buford".

They keyword in the query may have any number of sub-keywords, causing the code in the MySQL statement to change dynamically. My example code was generated with a keyword that has 2 sub-keywords. The part that seems not to be working is: "case when title like 'keyword1%' then 0 else 1 end asc" I am wondering if the code is in the wrong position in the comma delimited order sequence or if I should assign different numbers to 'then' and 'else'.

---

About my select code:

In my select statement if the keyword is "Buford Christmas" it's broken into "Buford" and "Christmas" and "Buford Christmas".

About this part of order code:

```
((title like '%keyword1%') + (title like '%keyword2%')) desc,
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers, with true being 1. So, this counts the number of matches.

Comment: you could be lazy and union the queries to make the ordering simpler

Comment: what is your requirement for sorting? is each key word treated the same? do you want Buford to have a higher precedence over Christmas?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. They keyword in the query may have any number of sub-keywords, causing the code in the MySQL statement to change dynamically. My example code was generated with a keyword that has 2 sub-keywords. The part that seems not to be working is: "case when title like 'keyword1%' then 0 else 1 end asc" I am wondering if the code is in the wrong position in the comma delimited sequence or if I should assign different numbers to 'then' and 'else'.

Answer (score 0):

```
select title 
  from books
    where title like '%buford christmas%'
      or title like '%buford%'
      or title like '%christmas%'
  order by
    case 
      when
        title = 'buford christmas' then 1
      when
        title like '%buford%' and title like '%christmas%' then 2
      when
        title like 'buford%' then 3
      when
        title like '%buford%' then 4
      when
        title like 'christmas%' then 5
      when 
        title like '%christmas%' then 6
      end 
    asc;
```

This will do what you're looking for. Obviously substitute variables for the literals there.  It prioritises results as such:

```
Books with title that EXACTLY matches the keywords
Books with titles that CONTAIN BOTH keywords
Books with titles that START with the first keyword
Books that CONTAIN the first keyword
Books that END with the last keyword
Books that CONTAIN the last keyword
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec62a/7

**edit**
You may also want to consider a fulltext index, eg: `create fulltext index ftx_title on books(title)`, you could then run your query as such:

```
select * 
  from books 
  where match(title) 
    against ('buford christmas' in boolean mode);
```

Which would make crafting your queries for keywords quite a bit simpler

Comment: Thank you for your reply. They keyword in the query may have any number of sub-keywords, causing the code in the MySQL statement to change dynamically. My example code was generated with a keyword that has 2 sub-keywords. The part that seems not to be working is: "case when title like 'keyword1%' then 0 else 1 end asc" I am wondering if the code is in the wrong position in the comma delimited sequence or if I should assign different numbers to 'then' and 'else'.

Comment: the comma is making it use sub-ordering.  what should your ordering precedence be? if you have three keywords, should it be books that match all three, books that match any two, books that match any one?

Comment: Yes. That is the way to order three keywords.

Comment: Then id really recommend the full text index. Not only is it simpler to implement, it will order your results based on how well they fit the search criteria. It wont give results in the exact order you requested due to the way it weights results, but you gain boolean keywords such as +keyword1 -keyword2